# Sending data back to specific clients using this multithread server

Tags: java, sockets

This is my java multithreading socketbased server, I need it to send data to the specific client who recieved data from, I don't think I need to add much, but still need guides if you will please:

```
public class Server {

 private static int port=4444, maxConnections=0;
 // Listen for incoming connections and handle them
 public static void main(String[] args) {
int i=0;

try{
  ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
  Socket server;

  while((i++ < maxConnections) || (maxConnections == 0)){
    doComms connection;

    server = listener.accept();
    doComms conn_c= new doComms(server);
    Thread t = new Thread(conn_c);
    t.start();
  }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
}

}

class doComms implements Runnable {
 private Socket server;
 private String line,input;

 doComms(Socket server) {
  this.server=server;
 }

 public void run () {

  input="";

  try {
    // Get input from the client
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());

    while((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.equals(".")) {
      input=input + line;
      out.println("I got:" + line);
    }

    // Now write to the client

    System.out.println("Overall message is:" + input);
    out.println("Overall message is:" + input);

    server.close();
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
    ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the issue? you are reading from a client and sending a message back to same client. Do you want something different?

Comment: yes in case of just 1 client its wokring. but im expecting about 1million clients, so i need some kind of ID for each client so can recognize them and a method for sending to specific client mate